# How to pass many temporary arrays to a subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran

Suppose I'm writing a Fortran subroutine that performs one time step of a simulation, and so will be called repeatedly.  To do its work, it requires many temporary arrays, which aren't meaningful or useful outside the subroutine.  The user may wish to perform several simulations of different sizes during the program's execution, maybe concurrently, but the dimensions of the arrays will be the same for all the time steps of a particular simulation.

How should I handle these temporary arrays?  Every way I can think of has some problem.

- If I were to use arrays local to the subroutine, they would either have to be put on the stack, which would limit how large they could be, or they would have to be allocated on the heap, which would waste time as the arrays would be allocated and deallocated every time step.
- Alternatively, the caller could allocate the arrays.  However, if the caller were to pass each array as a separate argument to the subroutine, the caller has to know how many arrays there are and how big each one is.  Furthermore, if the subroutine is modified in some way that changes the number or sizes of the arrays, every call to the subroutine would have to be modified.
- One technique I've seen is for the subroutine to accept a single large array and treat it as several temporary arrays concatenated together.  However, this seems risky, since an arithmetic error could lead to bugs that are hard to find.
- Finally, I could put all the temporary arrays into a derived type and write a separate subroutine to allocate all the arrays and another subroutine to free them.  This way, only a few subroutines have to know about the temporary arrays.  However, my understanding is that, at least until recent versions of Fortran, it would only be possible for the derived type to contain pointers to the arrays.  This would bring in all the disadvantages associated with using pointers (potential for bugs, aliasing, etc.).

Is there a way to do this that avoids these problems?  (Or is any of these problems less of a big deal than I think?)

Comment: Allocatable components were introduced with the "allocatable TR" (ISO/IEC TR 15581) that was published in 2001, and incorporated into the base language standard in Fortran 2003.  Most currently maintained Fortran compilers provided good support for them within a few years.  That's a bit beyond recent.

Comment: By default I'd allocate as local arrays and only go to a different approach if profiling showed there was an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use the save attribute on the arrays.

```
subroutine step(x, t, do_allocattion)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(:)
    double precision, intent(in) :: t
    logical, intent(in), optional :: do_allocation

    integer :: n
    double precision, allocatable, save :: work1(:), work2(:)
    n = size(x)

    if (present(do_allocation)) then
        if (do_allocation) then
            allocate(work1(n))
            allocate(work2(n))
        end if
    end if

    ! do work on x
end subroutine
```

EDIT: alternative solution, as I have mixed up with pointer arrays.

```
subroutine step(x, t)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(:)
    double precision, intent(in) :: t

    integer :: n
    double precision, allocatable, save :: work1(:), work2(:)
    n = size(x)

    if (.not. allocated(work1)) then
        allocate(work1(n))
    end if
    if (.not. allocated(work2)) then
        allocate(work2(n))
    end if

    ! do work on x
end subroutine
```

EDITED: Caution: you cannot simply check for "allocatedness" as it will be undefined when the program is started and the subroutine executed for the first time. You can add another optional argument to deallocate. -> This is the case for pointer arrays.

Comment: What do you mean by 'you cannot simply check for "allocatedness" as it will be undefined when the program is started'?  When execution starts the allocation status of all allocatable variables is defined as "unallocated".  Further, since Fortran 95 an allocation status of "undefined" hasn't existed.

Comment: Hi, I must have mixed with pointer arrays, as is hinted here: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html (look for "Big Danger with Undefined Pointers").

Comment: Yes, pointers without initialization start out as of undefined (_association_ rather than allocation) status.

Comment: Would this work if I was doing multiple simulations of different sizes?  (For example, what if the user started two simulations at the same time?)

Comment: If the code is part of a shared library, my first idea would be to define a derived type (DT) that holds allocatable arrays. The DT variable can be declared in the main program and passed, as a single argument, to the routine.

Comment: OK, I think that would be similar to the fourth option I listed in the original question.  IanH's comment (below the question) mentions that you could have allocatable arrays in derived types since 2003.  So maybe this is the best way to go if I think my code might be used in this way?

Comment: It seems simple and robust, so yes. I had not re-read the full question, by default SO focuses on last item :-/